# If else javascript error

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, var

I'm attempting to make a simple code so when you insert your name, it inserts it into the text, but if you don't insert your name it asks you to insert your name. The code seems like it should work, but it doesn't. Can anyone help me?

```
<body>

<h3>Please enter your name</h3>

<input type="text" id="name" value="" placeholder="Please enter your name">

<p id="dolly"></p>

<button onclick="yourName()">Enter</button>


<script>
function yourName() {
var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
if (x == "") {
document.getElementById("dolly").innerHTML = "Hello, " + x + ", My name is Dolly.";
} else {
document.getElementById("dolly").innerHTML = "Please enter your name.";
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Need `x == ""` or `x === ""`

Comment: Read your code out loud. If x is equal to an empty string, than display the name, else tell user to enter their name. Next thing, learn to use the developer console in your browser to locate errors, that will get you the syntax issue you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function yourName() {
var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
if (x.length != 0) {
document.getElementById("dolly").innerHTML = "Hello, " + x + ", My name is Dolly.";
} else {
document.getElementById("dolly").innerHTML = "Please enter your name.";
}
}
```

Comment: so just to be clear, you were missing the closing curly bracket for the function too.

Answer (score 1):

change `if (x == "")` to `if (x != "")` and close the function braces.

```html
<body>

<h3>Please enter your name</h3>

<input type="text" id="name" value="" placeholder="Please enter your name">

<p id="dolly"></p>

<button onclick="yourName()">Enter</button>


<script>
function yourName() {
  var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
  if (x != "") {
    document.getElementById("dolly").innerHTML = "Hello, " + x + ", My name is Dolly.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dolly").innerHTML = "Please enter your name.";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `if(x=="")` to `if(x!=="" && x.length!==0)` and also add a closing brace to close the function.
Full code is given below

```html
<body>

<h3>Please enter your name</h3>

<input type="text" id="name" value="" placeholder="Please enter your name">

<p id="dolly"></p>

<button onclick="yourName()">Enter</button>


<script>
function yourName() {
  var x = document.getElementById("name").value;
  if (x !== "" && x.length !==0) {
    document.getElementById("dolly").innerHTML = "Hello, " + x + ", My name is Dolly.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("dolly").innerHTML = "Please enter your name.";
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```